# How can i make the program to rerun itself in python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming right now and i know very less basic. I tried to create a calculator in python and it worked but i cant get it to rerun itself

i have tried things on some site but everything was way too complex for me to understand.

```
num1 = input("Enter your 1st number: ")
num2 = input("Enter your 2nd number: ")
choose_ope = input("Choose your operator: ")
if choose_ope == '+':
    print(float(num1) + float(num2))
elif choose_ope == '-':
    print(float(num1) - float(num2))
elif choose_ope == '*':
    print(float(num1) * float(num2))
elif choose_ope == '/':
    print(float(num1) / float(num2))

go_again = input("Do you want to go again ? : Y/N\n")
if go_again == 'Y':
    //i want the program to rerun itself here
else:
    print("OK!!")
```

If the user inputs Y i want the calculator to start again.
Detailed answers would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Check out `while` loops: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

Comment: Yes. I have learnt about while and for. I don't see how can i use while or for loop here.

Comment: If the loop exit condition can't be tested at the top of the loop, then just use `while True:` for the loop test.  This creates an infinite loop.  But inside the loop, you can force an exit by executing a `break` statement when you want to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over that code and `break` when you want to stop repeating:

```
while True: # Will start repeating here
    num1 = input("Enter your 1st number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter your 2nd number: ")
    choose_ope = input("Choose your operator: ")
    if choose_ope == '+':
        print(float(num1) + float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '-':
        print(float(num1) - float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '*':
        print(float(num1) * float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '/':
        print(float(num1) / float(num2))

    go_again = input("Do you want to go again ? : Y/N\n")
    if go_again != 'Y':
        print("OK!! Exiting")
        break # break to leave the loop

    # It will loop automatically back to the top otherwise
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by writing this in a function and make it as recursive function like below.

```
def calculator():
    num1 = input("Enter your 1st number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter your 2nd number: ")
    choose_ope = input("Choose your operator: ")
    if choose_ope == '+':
        print(float(num1) + float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '-':
        print(float(num1) - float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '*':
        print(float(num1) * float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '/':
        print(float(num1) / float(num2))

    go_again = input("Do you want to go again ? : Y/N\n")
    if go_again == 'Y':
        calculator()
    else:
        print("OK!!")

calculator()
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this, as making this recursive unnecessarily scales up the stack, slowing performance and eventually crashing your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while loop` that will run the code again until the input is different from `Y`:

```
go_again = 'Y'

while go_again == 'Y':
    num1 = input("Enter your 1st number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter your 2nd number: ")
    choose_ope = input("Choose your operator: ")
    if choose_ope == '+':
        print(float(num1) + float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '-':
        print(float(num1) - float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '*':
        print(float(num1) * float(num2))
    elif choose_ope == '/':
        print(float(num1) / float(num2))

   go_again = input("Do you want to go again ? : Y/N\n")
   if go_again == 'Y':
       print("while loop will run again")
   else:
       print("program will exit")
```